# Regex character class subtraction with negative groups

Tags: regex, xsd, xpath-2.0

This question relates to character class subtraction in regular expression (regex). I refer to the regex flavour of XPATH 2.0 second edition.

When there are negative groups within a character class subtraction, does the subtract operator (-) occur before? or after the negative group operator (^)?

The text of the XPATH/ XML schema specification is below. But to my mind, it reads ambiguously.

> For any ·positive character group· or ·negative character group· G,
>   and any ·character class expression· C, G-C is a valid ·character
>   class subtraction·, identifying the set of all characters in C(G) that
>   are not also in C(C).

To be more specific, consider the following three regexes:

1. [^abc-[ad]]
2. [^abc-[^ad]]
3. [abc-[^ad]]

being matched against the haystack text of:

- abcdef

What are the possible match texts (first and subsequent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that text is ambiguous, if we are lenient enough to read `G-C` as `[G-[C]]`, and a negative group, `^G`, as `[^G]`. Now, it looks clear that the caret is part of the first group, and does not negate both groups.

Therefore, `[^abc-[ad]]` would match:

> {All Characters Besides `a`, `b` and `c`} [\](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) {`a` and `d`} = { All Characters Besides `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`}

Keep in mind, you can easily test to see the behavior `:)`.
As a bonus, .Net regular expressions also support this feature, making it a little easier to [test online](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=fbf8bcb8-fec4-44a4-bf5b-bfeda65aa72e).
See also: [Character Class Subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction)

Comment: Thanks. The online tester is especially usefull.